# Why would the identity of the father's mohel be relevant to a potential shidduch?

Tags: brit-milah, shidduchim-dating

A few in my neighborhood mentioned that they saw, on a shidduch resume asked "Who was the father's mohel?" My wife was asked this question from a shadchan. (No ... my wife is not dating anyone else :-)

I don't mean to sound funny, but seriously, I was too young to recall who my mohel was. If I saw him today, I know I wouldn't recognize him so many years later. (Chances are, the mohel is now doing a brit in *shamayim*.) Besides, I have no relative alive who was at my brit, whom I could ask.

I'm really curious as to why a shadchan, a girl, or a girl's parents would need to know this information. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a thought, but couldn't it be in order to verify that it was truly a "kosher" brit with a "kosher" mohel? Especially in our days when it is common for non jews to also do brits.

Comment: @Voctave The focus of my question is why knowing the father's mohel is relevant to a shidduch. A guess - does the mohel have anything to do with *yichut* ("heritage")?

Comment: @DanF Yichus is spelled יחוס, not יחות.

Comment: @Heshy Thanks for the correction. I have dixsleaik and a slight lips :-)

Comment: @DanF #ashkenaziproblems ;-)

Comment: @DanF by recent resume, do you mean a standard form issued by an org when you sign up for jewish online dating or pay a dating coach, or join a shadchan's data base etc. can you link to the form you saw so we can see who is asking and the full form? OR did you mean that the girl's private resume has a list of questions for potential suitors? What do you mean?

Comment: @DavidKenner You asked a good Q, and it's tough to give a definitive answer. My son is handling most of the process, here, and he's not really willing to volunteer full info, so much of this is hearsay. IN this case, I understand that this is a private resume. Some in my neighborhood have told me that it occasionally appears on a shadchan's resume form. A bit more frequently, some side (girl or boy's parents') ask this info and relay it via the shadchan or ask the other parent, directly. For purposes of this Q, the method shouldn't matter. I'm just curious as to why this info is "crucial".

Comment: Possibly off topic as about Jews, not Judaism? People ask crazy things about Shiduchim, some people might consider it important, some people think it's pointless. And regarding your note in the bounty "Besides, isn't this somewhat private info, anyway?", that doesn't really matter. A person is asking presumably because they feel it's important (for whatever reason), and they're entitled to ask whatever they want (and it's most likely Assur to lie in this situation). Of course, you can always respond with "that's a ridiculous question". :)

Comment: Funny and somewhat related anecdote that I heard said about Rav Yaakov Kamenetzy: A man in his 20's meets Reb Yaakov and during the course of the conversation mentions that Reb Yaakov was the Sandek at his Bris. Reb Yaakov responds "My apologies for not recognizing you" :)

Comment: Sounds like a great way to discover if your parents cared about Judaism (and provide hints as to _their_ Jewishness).

Comment: @Salmononius2 Funny. If I remember, I'll ask his grandson about this story. I see him, occasionally. I somewhat agree w/ your last comment. Most likely, after the bounty expires, I'll delete this Q. I think this one will just remain unanswered, and the reason for the people sking abouit the father's mohel is completely speculative.

Comment: @DannySchoemann See ^^^ re my general feeling about this question at this point. Re your point , there are more direct ways to find out your suggested info. The name of the mohel doesn't reveal anything to the other parents unless he's heard of the man, perhaps. Even then, it would say more about the boy / girl's grandfather, as he was the one who chose the mohel, not the father. As I said, in my case,  I can't provide any info. So, b/c of such missing info, someone would rule out my son? I don't get it. But, again, there are numerous mysteries in *frumkeit*.

Comment: @DanF - Agreed. If you have no clue about your Mohel's identity and have no way of finding that out, then I now know that when you were born your parents didn't live in a thriving Jewish community. That tells me a lot - i.e. that I have no easy way to discover "how Jewish" they were. Your son is now collateral damage, but, remember,  he doesn't become Jewish simply because you're now an upstanding member of a great Jewish community. (Yes, there may be more direct ways to ask this, but this seems a rather _polite_ way of asking. - What do they do for the mother's side, I'm curious to know.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann Re your 1st sentence: What in heaven are you talking about??? People such as me move from place to place. Parents and relatives die. It's not as if while someone is a child or adult, he asked his father, "What was the name of my mohel?" and makes a note of that in case 30 years later, some stranger asks that info. How does that lack of knowledge correlate with not being in a thriving Jewish community? I really don't see how you arrived at that conclusion.

Comment: @DanF - because if your parents were part of a thriving community then any old-timer of that community could be consulted about who was _the Mohel_ at the time you were born. (And mostly there's one snipper who has a virtual monopoly.) You could then give an almost absolute answer, even if the Mohel didn't keep records.

Comment: @DanF - And that's why it's not _private info_ - I never asked, and was never told who my Mohel was, but I know who he is and I can name about 30 live people who were present - unless they missed shul because they were ill/on vacation that day. And I know where it was without ever having been told. And that once-thriving community is no longer; 5+ decades is a long time in a decaying neighborhood/country.

Comment: Hi @DannySchoemann I think we're just going to disagree on this one. We're coming from different sides of the picture. My former community has no Jewish old timers. Regardless, I think that getting this info is irrelevant to knowing much about the girl or boy, anyway. There are more critical matters than this one. I'm prob. going to delete this Q today or tomorrow.

Comment: I vaguely remember that one of my sons had a chashuv mohel because I was told that the mohel I asked could not do it but his father did. however, I do not remember his name. My second son I remember the name of the mohel, but not because of the milah, but because of other circumstances at that time. I would have no idea of the name of the mohel for my third son, though he was probably the one that most people in the community used at that time. That would show that it seems to be a ridiculous question that does not prove anything.

Comment: @sabbahillel Thanks. It looks like this question will be closed, anyway.